# I extracted a file using binwalk. I discovered it has a TROC file, how do I read or extract the contents of the TROC file?

Tags: computer-forensics, ctf, binwalk

| DECIMAL | HEXADECIMAL | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33211 | 0x81BB | TROC filesystem, 1263425345 file entries |
| 948694 | 0xE79D6 | StuffIt Deluxe Segment (data): f:IK |

Answer (score 0):

Just use `binwalk --dd='.*' <filename>`, then you can extract all of the possible files by their offset.

Answer (score 0):

Binwalk is useless for this puzzle. Both signatures it finds are false positives.
Just look through the file with a HEX viewer. The file type and data are correct.
Well, almost... No more hints from me.